# if statement that checks div condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have 5 different divs - they are all set to `display: none;`
When the user clicks, the divs become visible (`display: block;`)

I want to make an if statement that checks if the divs have a value of `display: block;` and once they do, I want another div to pop-up.

Is this possible? Very new to javascript and I'm trying to be creative and learn. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its very easy to do but you really need to give a few more details as to what exactly you want this to look like. There's more than one way to skin a cat

Comment: make two css classes : "hide{display : none}" and "show{display:block}" and give the divs hide class if you want to hide them and check for hide class to know if they are hidden

Comment: Hi Jakob! In addition to Christopher's request for details, please show anything you've tried. Questions that are focused and show code that has been tried are easier to answer.

Comment: @Jakob When you click do all the divs show? Or just the one the user clicks on?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="DivId">Block to check<div>
<div id="MessageBlock">Message to be gives</div>

<div onclick="runCode();">CLICK HERE</div> //user clicks on this and it runs code

<script>
function runCode(){
if(document.getElementById("DivId").style.display == "block")//Code checks if div "DivID is block"
    document.getElementById("MessageBlock").style.display = "block";//Do something such as show message block
}
</script>
```

Hope this puts you in the right direction

Comment: You really need to give more details on what you want this to look like. As I said above there's more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: I'm not the OP, so I can not give more info. :P

Comment: Each DIV till have to have a different ID

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with plain JavaScript, or you're using jQuery?

```
if (getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("div"))[display] === 'block')
    document.getElementById("anotherdiv").style[display] = 'block';
```

Hope this helps